# Double Get Send Data

Tags: php, html, get

In this page : `page.php?id=value`

I've this html's code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="key" />
<input type="submit" name="send />
</form>
```

It's redirect me to: `page.php?key=value` , i want to redirect to: `page.php?id=value&key=value` , how i can do it? I must redirect it to this page with PHP ?

Comment: *Insight* => [`key`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) - *"this is for a search system"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put everything you want on the next page in your form:

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'];?>" />
 <input type="text" name="key" />
 <input type="submit" name="send />
</form>
```

Really though, you should be using POST to send data, and the above code is NOT secure (allows anything in a url to easily end up in a form that could create some sql injection or XSS type issues.

Comment: SQL Injection is not an issue here, but could you please just fix the XSS vulnerability? :)

Comment: this is for a search system , and i control , so thy ;)

Answer (score 2):

simply,

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
    <input type="text" name="key" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: I dont think the op intended that id is literally `'value'`

Answer (score 1):

You can have the **id** as a hidden input in your form

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $my_id; /*Suppose this variable contain your value */  ?>" name="id" />
   <input type="text" name="key" />
   <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work. The query string in the action is over written when the new query string is created from the form inputs. and you missed a `"` after `name="send`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the form's action set to the page you want it to submit to. If it is blank it will just  submit to the same page.

```
<form action="page.php?id=value&key=value" method="get">
<input type="text" name="key" />
<input type="submit" name="send />
</form>
```

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Actually yes you can. It is very much possible and a tool I use quite often. Test it out before you down vote my answer. `<?php
echo $_GET['fromform'];
?>
<form action="test6.php?fromform=youcan" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

Comment: Opp. is asking for form's `method=get` solution .. in your example in comment its `method=post`. `GET` Method refuses what variables being used in query string.

Comment: If form's method is `GET` then the variables in url will completely ignored and only it's fields containing `name` attribute will be considered. Check this code http://pastebin.com/AreUJHeM